# Install bootstrap-table-rails in Rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to install bootstrap-table-rails gem from the following link: [Click](https://github.com/bjevanchiu/bootstrap-table-rails). The problem is that this gem was probably made for Rails 4 and therefore every time I have to install an "old" gem in Rails 5/6 I have difficulties.

I followed the gem's GitHub page instructions to the letter and I checked that the gem was installed in the path:

```
/home/debian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootstrap-table-rails-1.13.4/lib/bootstrap-table-rails
```

and not in the node_modules dir of my app. By he way I tried to add in
my application.js and application.scss file are as follows:

application.js

```
import 'bootstrap'
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
require("jquery-ui")
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all";
require("leaflet");
require("easy-autocomplete")

//= require bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table
```

application.scss

```
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self



 */

@import "leaflet/dist/leaflet";
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
@import 'easy-autocomplete/dist/easy-autocomplete';
```

The problem is that when I use the example code of Bootstrap-Table, I receive this error in my browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $table.bootstrapTable is not a function
```

The code I used:

```
  <div class="select">
    <select class="form-control" id="locale">
      <option value="af-ZA">af-ZA</option>
      <option value="ar-SA">ar-SA</option>
      <option value="ca-ES">ca-ES</option>
      <option value="cs-CZ">cs-CZ</option>
      <option value="da-DK">da-DK</option>
      <option value="de-DE">de-DE</option>
      <option value="el-GR">el-GR</option>
      <option value="en-US" selected>en-US</option>
      <option value="es-AR">es-AR</option>
      <option value="es-CL">es-CL</option>
      <option value="es-CR">es-CR</option>
      <option value="es-ES">es-ES</option>
      <option value="es-MX">es-MX</option>
      <option value="es-NI">es-NI</option>
      <option value="es-SP">es-SP</option>
      <option value="et-EE">et-EE</option>
      <option value="eu-EU">eu-EU</option>
      <option value="fa-IR">fa-IR</option>
      <option value="fi-FI">fi-FI</option>
      <option value="fr-BE">fr-BE</option>
      <option value="fr-FR">fr-FR</option>
      <option value="he-IL">he-IL</option>
      <option value="hr-HR">hr-HR</option>
      <option value="hu-HU">hu-HU</option>
      <option value="id-ID">id-ID</option>
      <option value="it-IT">it-IT</option>
      <option value="ja-JP">ja-JP</option>
      <option value="ka-GE">ka-GE</option>
      <option value="ko-KR">ko-KR</option>
      <option value="ms-MY">ms-MY</option>
      <option value="nb-NO">nb-NO</option>
      <option value="nl-NL">nl-NL</option>
      <option value="pl-PL">pl-PL</option>
      <option value="pt-BR">pt-BR</option>
      <option value="pt-PT">pt-PT</option>
      <option value="ro-RO">ro-RO</option>
      <option value="ru-RU">ru-RU</option>
      <option value="sk-SK">sk-SK</option>
      <option value="sv-SE">sv-SE</option>
      <option value="th-TH">th-TH</option>
      <option value="tr-TR">tr-TR</option>
      <option value="uk-UA">uk-UA</option>
      <option value="ur-PK">ur-PK</option>
      <option value="uz-Latn-UZ">uz-Latn-UZ</option>
      <option value="vi-VN">vi-VN</option>
      <option value="zh-CN">zh-CN</option>
      <option value="zh-TW">zh-TW</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="toolbar">
    <button id="remove" class="btn btn-danger" disabled>
      <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete
    </button>
  </div>
  <table
    id="table"
    data-toolbar="#toolbar"
    data-search="true"
    data-show-refresh="true"
    data-show-toggle="true"
    data-show-fullscreen="true"
    data-show-columns="true"
    data-show-columns-toggle-all="true"
    data-detail-view="true"
    data-show-export="true"
    data-click-to-select="true"
    data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter"
    data-minimum-count-columns="2"
    data-show-pagination-switch="true"
    data-pagination="true"
    data-id-field="id"
    data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, all]"
    data-show-footer="true"
    data-side-pagination="server"
    data-url="https://examples.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/bootstrap_table/data"
    data-response-handler="responseHandler">
  </table>


  <script>
    var $table = $('#table')
    var $remove = $('#remove')
    var selections = []

    function getIdSelections() {
      return $.map($table.bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function (row) {
        return row.id
      })
    }

    function responseHandler(res) {
      $.each(res.rows, function (i, row) {
        row.state = $.inArray(row.id, selections) !== -1
      })
      return res
    }

    function detailFormatter(index, row) {
      var html = []
      $.each(row, function (key, value) {
        html.push('<p><b>' + key + ':</b> ' + value + '</p>')
      })
      return html.join('')
    }

    function operateFormatter(value, row, index) {
      return [
        '<a class="like" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Like">',
        '<i class="fa fa-heart"></i>',
        '</a>  ',
        '<a class="remove" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Remove">',
        '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>',
        '</a>'
      ].join('')
    }

    window.operateEvents = {
      'click .like': function (e, value, row, index) {
        alert('You click like action, row: ' + JSON.stringify(row))
      },
      'click .remove': function (e, value, row, index) {
        $table.bootstrapTable('remove', {
          field: 'id',
          values: [row.id]
        })
      }
    }

    function totalTextFormatter(data) {
      return 'Total'
    }

    function totalNameFormatter(data) {
      return data.length
    }

    function totalPriceFormatter(data) {
      var field = this.field
      return '$' + data.map(function (row) {
        return +row[field].substring(1)
      }).reduce(function (sum, i) {
        return sum + i
      }, 0)
    }

    function initTable() {
      $table.bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable({
        height: 550,
        locale: $('#locale').val(),
        columns: [
          [{
            field: 'state',
            checkbox: true,
            rowspan: 2,
            align: 'center',
            valign: 'middle'
          }, {
            title: 'Item ID',
            field: 'id',
            rowspan: 2,
            align: 'center',
            valign: 'middle',
            sortable: true,
            footerFormatter: totalTextFormatter
          }, {
            title: 'Item Detail',
            colspan: 3,
            align: 'center'
          }],
          [{
            field: 'name',
            title: 'Item Name',
            sortable: true,
            footerFormatter: totalNameFormatter,
            align: 'center'
          }, {
            field: 'price',
            title: 'Item Price',
            sortable: true,
            align: 'center',
            footerFormatter: totalPriceFormatter
          }, {
            field: 'operate',
            title: 'Item Operate',
            align: 'center',
            clickToSelect: false,
            events: window.operateEvents,
            formatter: operateFormatter
          }]
        ]
      })
      $table.on('check.bs.table uncheck.bs.table ' +
        'check-all.bs.table uncheck-all.bs.table',
      function () {
        $remove.prop('disabled', !$table.bootstrapTable('getSelections').length)

        // save your data, here just save the current page
        selections = getIdSelections()
        // push or splice the selections if you want to save all data selections
      })
      $table.on('all.bs.table', function (e, name, args) {
        console.log(name, args)
      })
      $remove.click(function () {
        var ids = getIdSelections()
        $table.bootstrapTable('remove', {
          field: 'id',
          values: ids
        })
        $remove.prop('disabled', true)
      })
    }

    $(function() {
      initTable()

      $('#locale').change(initTable)
    })
  </script>
```

For sure the problem is that I don't have added properly the gem...What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

After installing with `yarn add bootstrap-table-sticky-header`, I've added this line in application.js:

```
import 'bootstrap-table';
```

And this line in application.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css";
```

Maybe is not the most correct, but it works.